# Website not accessible hosted on IIS withing same network

Tags: iis, hosting

I have hosted a site on local IIS server and able to access it using IP address on desktop connected within the same network but getting error while accessing the same on Mac using the same WiFi network but, I am getting error as "Access Denied"

Answer (score 0):

What is the authentication mechanism used? Did you turn it off and still get access denied?